# How to check if json array of values present in one table is present in another table using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables that look like this..

**Baskets**

| id | Array |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `["Apple", "Mango", "Pineapple"]` |
| 2 | `["Mango", "Pineapple"]` |
| 3 | `["Dragonfruit"]` |

**Stock**

| Fruit | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 100 |
| Mango | 500 |
| Kiwi | 99 |
| Grapes | 0 |

Through a SQL query, I have to check how many fruits from an array of the first table are present in the second table.

For example, out of `["Apple", "Mango", "Pineapple"]` only `Apple` and `Mango` is in the Stock table.

**Expected outcome:**

| id | available |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |

PS. this is a simplification of the actual problem I'm trying to solve, my main query is how to match a JSON array of objects against some other table. The fruits/stock example is just for explaining the problem.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using MongoDB instead of MySQL

Comment: That is not under my control. @Stewart

Comment: Mongo would be if you wanted to do it with JS and not learn the SQL which is pretty concise in the accepted answer and I bet many times faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT Baskets.id, COUNT(Stock.Fruit) available
FROM Baskets 
LEFT JOIN Stock ON JSON_SEARCH(Baskets.Array, 'one', Stock.Fruit) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Baskets.id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a0f8e8fba8851fcda508affca0201ba9